# Correct Structure for storing data in realtime DB Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a mobile app, on which user can register with mobile_number. When one user is registered successfully app asks to access contact directory permission from user. After user gives required permission, I store user's contact numbers to firebase DB.

Later if new user registers, i want to see which of his contacts are already registered with my app, and send them a in-app notification like following:

> Your friend/Contact ABC has registered on XYZ app, welcome him/her.

I am currently storing data in firebase realtime DB in following format.

```
contacts/"+registeredUserMobileNo+"/contacts/"+UserContactNumber1);

contacts/"+registeredUserMobileNo+"/contacts/"+UserContactNumber2);
```

How can i check using current data that how many of his contacts already registered with my app?

Is there a better structure of DB i can create?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you denormalize the data and create two different nodes:

The first node would be exactly the one you mention in your post:

```
- contacts
   - registerUserId1
       - userContacts
           - userContactNumber1: true
           - UserContactNumber2: true
   - registerUserId2
       - userContacts
           - userContactNumber3: true
           - userContactNumber4: true
           - UserContactNumber2: true
```

The second node would contain the list of `UserContactNumber` (i.e. the ones from the contact directories) in such a way you can easily fetch the users to which you have to send an alert when one of these UserContactNumber becomes a user of the app. Like the following:

```
- userContactNumbers
   - userContactNumber1
       - registerUserId1: true
   - userContactNumber2
       - registerUserId1: true
       - registerUserId2: true
   - userContactNumber3
       - registerUserId1: true
   - userContactNumber4
       - registerUserId1: true
```

Then, when a new user registers, you just have to query the userContactNumbers node to see if it contains the new user number, and if it is the case, you send the alerts accordingly to the list of numbers.

In order to keep these two nodes in sync, you should use the `update()` method, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) in the doc.